# How to access changed items count using app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo from script

Tags: javascript, api, grep, adobe-indesign

```
function changeGrep(toFind, toChange) {
  // clear input field
  app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;

  // search preferences
  app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeFootnotes = true;
  app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeHiddenLayers = true;
  app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = false;
  app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = false;
  app.findChangeGrepOptions.includeMasterPages = true;

  app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = toFind;

  // this method does not give the desired effect
  var elementsToChange = app.changeGrepPreferences.getElements();
  alert(elementsToChange.length);

  app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = toChange;

  // clear input field
  app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
}
```

Which command will collect the array of the changed elements?
After executing the script, I want to display in an alert a message about the number of matches found and the number of changes

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
app.activeDocumnet.changeGrep().length
```

This command gets an array with the length of matches